# Model and behavior use in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mapping

i have an issue with a table users that has manytomany relation with a table named missions.
the problem is there's a table missions_users that it has three foreign key in it the user_id,manager_id,mission_id.
the user_id and  manager_id both reference to the same table users.
so

```
manager_id -->users
user_id -->users
mission_id -->missions
```

so how i can achieve that in cakephp, ad map this relation in cakephp model.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Cakephp 2.x

You want to implement the [hasMany through](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model) association. You will need to create a model (assume its called MissionUser) based on the missions_users table.

- MissionUser **belongsTo** to User (twice - once for user_id, once for manager_id)
- MissionUser **belongsTo** Mission.
- Mission **hasMany** MissionUser.
- User **hasMany** MissionUser (as User)
- User **hasMany** MissionUser (as a manager)